# Listing RPM's in a Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

So I have been tasked with creating some clean up jobs in Jenkins and one of the stages is gathering a list of all the RPM's then filtering them based on the set up and deleting the appropriate RPMS's.

I of course have to script this job and have no clue where to even start or how to even attempt to get a list of the RPM's if someone could point me in the right direction of provide me with some scripts that would be great :) Struggling to find resources that could help me, so any support would be appreciated.

Kind regards,

IA

Comment: are those RPM files stored somewhere?

Comment: Yeah the RPM files are stored on a remote server.